# How do I transform the equation based on this condition?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

If a and b are the roots of the equation $$2x^2-px+7=0$$ Then a-b is a root of ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, $a+b=\frac{p}{2}$  and $ab=\frac{7}{2}$

If $y=a-b=>y^2=(a+b)^2-4ab$

$=>y^2=(\frac{p}{2})^2-4 \frac{7}{2}$

So, a-b is a root of $4y^2-p^2+56=0$